# Understanding Rust Components iterator for absolute and relative paths via example

Tags: rust, iterator

From [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html) I understand that the `components` method produces an iterator over the `Components` of `std::path::Path`. In particular, the type [`Components`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/path.rs.html#557-573) is defined as:

```
pub struct Components<'a> {
// The path left to parse components from
path: &'a [u8],

// The prefix as it was originally parsed, if any
prefix: Option<Prefix<'a>>,

// true if path *physically* has a root separator; for most Windows
// prefixes, it may have a "logical" rootseparator for the purposes of
// normalization, e.g.,  \\server\share == \\server\share\.
has_physical_root: bool,

// The iterator is double-ended, and these two states keep track of what has
// been produced from either end
front: State,
back: State,
}
```

and consequently,

```
pub fn components(&self) -> Components<'_> {
    let prefix = parse_prefix(self.as_os_str());
    Components {
        path: self.as_u8_slice(),
        prefix,
        has_physical_root: has_physical_root(self.as_u8_slice(), prefix)
            || has_redox_scheme(self.as_u8_slice()),
        front: State::Prefix,
        back: State::Body,
    }
}
```

However, I still have difficulty understanding the iterator in action. I would appreciate it if somebody could explain (ideally with an example) what `Components` members hold after each call to the `next` method for an absolute and/or relative path.

Comment: Looking through its [`next()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/path.rs.html#837-883) implementation would be the most direct way to figure out what its doing.